# Soap Request Using Node.Js

Tags: java, c#, node.js, soap, wsdl

I have to connect to some service which uses `SOAP 1.1 standard` and they send me documentation with classes written in C# and Java. 
I can't establish connection, it gives me error 400 bad request. I never had experience with SOAP requests, nor C# and Java.
All I can put here is this code

```
const wsse    = require('wsse');


const token = wsse({ username: config.get('serviceToConnect.auth.testUsername'), password: config.get('serviceToConnect.auth.testPassword') });
 // e.g. 'UsernameToken Username="bob", PasswordDigest="quR/EWLAV4xLf9Zqyw4pDmfV9OY=", Nonce="d36e316282959a9ed4c89851497a717f", Created="2003-12-15T14:43:07Z"'
request.post(
            {
                url:   config.get('serviceToConnect.url.sessionRequestUrl'),
                body:     new Buffer(bodyRequest),
                encoding: 'utf-8',
                headers:  {
                    'Content-Type':   'text/xml; charset=utf-8',
                    'Content-Length': bodyRequest.length,
                    'Security':       token.getWSSEHeader(),
                    'SOAPAction':     'urn:#AuthenticateUser'
                }
            })
```

This is the wsdl file. I guess I need to extract SOAP Action URL. But what is it? Ps. I replaced original Url with www.myService.com

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions name="SessionRequestWSDL" targetNamespace="http://www.myService.com/webservices/SessionRequest"
    xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://www.myService.com/webservices/SessionRequest" xmlns:ns="http://www.myService.com/webservices/SessionRequest" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">
    <types>
        <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.myService.com/webservices/SessionRequest">
            <xsd:import namespace="http://www.myService.com/webservices/SessionRequest" schemaLocation="../schema/SessionRequest.xsd"/>
        </xsd:schema>
    </types>
    <message name="SessionRequestOperationRequest">
        <part name="part1" element="tns:SessionRequest"/>
    </message>
    <message name="SessionRequestOperationResponse">
        <part name="part1" element="tns:SessionRequest-Response"/>
    </message>
    <portType name="SessionRequestPortType">
        <operation name="SessionRequest">
            <input name="input1" message="tns:SessionRequestOperationRequest"/>
            <output name="output1" message="tns:SessionRequestOperationResponse"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="SessionRequestBinding" type="tns:SessionRequestPortType">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <operation name="SessionRequest">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:#AuthenticateUser"/>
            <input name="input1">
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output name="output1">
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="SessionRequestService">
        <port name="SessionRequestPort" binding="tns:SessionRequestBinding">
        <!-- NOTICE: The service location URL below is NOT VALID
             Valid service URLs will be provided by your MyService.Net Project Manager -->
            <soap:address location="http://localhost/SessionRequestService/SessionRequestPort"/>
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

The main question - am I sending the right SoapAction Url.
Also, they said I need to send WS addressing `To` and `From`, and that they will supply me with that, but they did not. For `From` I guess my domain, and to is URL service? Is that something that should go to header or in xml body request?

This is part of their code, that uses their library writen in Java for implementing web service.

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
BigInteger applicationID = BigInteger.valueOf(12345);
UserModel userModel = null;
UserType user = null;
// Get an instance of the webservice client service
// This library will expect the wsdl file to be available at
/xml-resources/web-service-references/SessionRequest/wsdl/SessionRequest.wsdl at runtime
(where the root directory is the root of the packaged java classes )
// The associated schemas will also need to be available in their correct relative
locations to the wsdl file.
//
// Alternately, set the location of the wsdl file at runtime using the
setLocalWSDL() method.
// Refer to the WebserviceClient class javadoc for details.
SessionRequestService client =
WebserviceClient.create(SessionRequestService.class);
SessionRequestPortType port = client.getSessionRequestPort();
//set webservice endpoint and add a username token
WebserviceClient.setEndpoint(port, new
URL("http://service.url/that/will/be/provided"));
WebserviceClient.setUsernameToken(port, new UsernameToken("some-id",
"the-password"));
try
{
...
```